# Regular Expression matching using Lambda Expressions

Tags: c#, regex, linq, lambda

I am trying to implement a wildcard search Functionlity for (*,?) using LINQ to SQL. As of now, I want to try it using Regular expression as the code we write will be short and easily manageable. Here is what I have

```
  string kw=_keyword.Replace("*",".*").Replace("?",".");
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<DAL.RequestAttribute>();
        Regex reg=new Regex("^"+kw+"$");
        predicate=predicate &&(reg.IsMatch(ra=>ra.AttributeValue));
```

So, here it gives a compilation error as "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"

Though some workarounds if I make it compile and run, I get this runtime Error

"Method 'Boolean IsMatch(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL."

So, I have two Questions here
1. Am I thinking in right lanes to implement my wildcard using Regular Expressions? if not, which is more efficient way to do this?
2. How to resolve this error .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could mimic SQL's LIKE operator by using SqlMethods.Like: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Just be sure to use the appropriate wildcards/tokens: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx.

Update:
You cannot use regular expressions with simple SQL. Since you are essentially building a SQL statement via LINQ, the same rule applies. Though, it's still not quite clear where you are tapping into LINQ with the sample code you've provided.

I would typically expect to see something like the following:

```
var results = 
  from Something in SomeLinqContext 
  where SqlMethods.Like(Something.Value, kw);
```

Comment: This SQL's like method is also not working as the first error is popping up again. Here is my code I tried  string kw=_keyword.Replace("*","%").Replace("?","_");
            var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<DAL.RequestAttribute>();
            Regex reg=new Regex("^"+kw+"$");
            predicate=predicate && (System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods.Like((ra=>ra.AttributeValue),kw)); I get the error in the last line as stated..

Comment: Updating my answer to clarify something.

Comment: In a more manual processing I got the code like following for "* "                          string[] _searchParts = _keyword.Split('*');
 if (_searchParts.Length == 2)
{
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_searchParts[0]))
 {
   if (_fieldName == null)
  predicate = (ra => ra.AttributeValue.EndsWith(_searchParts[1])
   && ra.Attribute.LibID == _libID);
   else
predicate = (ra => ra.AttributeValue.EndsWith(_searchParts[1])
&& ra.Attribute.LibID == _libID
&& ra.Attribute.Name == _fieldName);

                } This works Okay and I am using Predicatebuilder class at "http://www.albahari.com/expressions"

Comment: Where/how are you using the predicate?

Comment: I am using Predicate to filter the records when using the LINQ Query. Therefore..PFB a simple analogy..I build a predicate as follows..predicate=predicatebuilder.True<DAL.RequestAttribute>(); and add on conditions to this like..predicate=(ra=>ra.AttributeValue.Endswith("abc") &&ra.Attribute.LibID=26; Now I use this predicate in the LINQ Query as DAL.LibMgmtDataClassesDataContext dCtx = DAL.LibMgmtDataClassesDataContext.GetDataContext();
            return (from ra in dCtx.RequestAttributes.Where(requestAttributesExpr) select ra.Request.RequestID).Distinct().ToList<int>();

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found an answer to my question. Thanks to Ventaur for the Suggestion. the solution is on similar lines but just a bit different. PFB the code for it

```
string kw=_keyword.Replace("*","%").Replace("?","_");
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<DAL.RequestAttribute>();
predicate = (ra => SqlMethods.Like(ra.AttributeValue, kw) && <Any other boolean conditions>
```

Therefore it boils down to how to make an expression out of SQLMethods.like method using our predicate builder class.